# How do i return an array to display from backwards

Tags: java, logic, explain

hey so am new in java and haven't gotten in my head the logic on how to print an array backwards. I just don't understand how it flows using forloop

its fairly easy and chatgpt could easily do it whats bothering me though is i dont understand it so if it could be provided with proper explanation i would appreciate it

this is an example of what i mean {1,2,3,4,5}

display would be - {5,4,3,2,1}

Answer (score 1):

do you mean:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // your array
        int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};

        // loop to print the array backwards
        for(int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank u, yes thats what i mean i've been getting confused lately on java

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> i dont understand it so if it could be provided with proper explanation

### Arrays

As shown in [The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) by Oracle Corp, a `for` loop has three parts:

```java
for ( initialization ; termination ; increment ) 
{
    statement(s)
}
```

Take for example an array `{ "alpha" , "beta" , "gamma" }`:

```java
for ( int index = 0 ; index < myArray.length ; index ++ )
{
    System.out.println( "Index: " + index + ", value: " + myArray[ index ] );
}
```

See this [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/EsDnUk).

```
------|  Ascending  |----------
Index: 0, Value: alpha
Index: 1, Value: beta
Index: 2, Value: gamma
```

To reverse the direction:

- The first part, ***initialization***, can start at the *last* index of the array rather than at the *first* index (zero). Ex: `int index = ( myArray.length - 1 )`. (Parentheses optional there.)
- The second part, ***termination***, can test for going past the first index (zero), into negative numbers: `index > -1` (or `index >= 0`).
- The third part, ***increment***, can go downwards (negative) rather than upwards (positive): `index --`.

```java
for ( int index = ( myArray.length - 1 ) ; index > -1 ; index -- )
{
    System.out.println( "Index: " + index + ", value: " + myArray[ index ] );
}
```

See this [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/EsDnUk).

```
------|  Descending  |----------
Index: 2, value: gamma
Index: 1, value: beta
Index: 0, value: alpha
```

### Collections

The code above certainly works. And, on the upside, arrays tend to use less memory while executing faster. But, on the downside, working with arrays is limiting, cumbersome, and somewhat error-prone.

More commonly in Java, we use the [*Java Collections Framework*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework).

In collections, the appropriate replacement for an array is a [`SequencedCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html) such as [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html) (a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/List.html)) or [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html) (a [`NavigableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html)).

We can easily make an [unmodifiable](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable) `List` of our array by calling [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)). (The concrete actually used under-the-covers is unspecified.) The `List.of` method performs a *shallow copy*. This means the content of the elements is *not* duplicated — the same three `String` object are in both the original array *and* in the new `List`.

Every `List` is also a `SequencedCollection`. This means we can call the [`reversed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html#reversed()) method. This method is quite efficient in that it does *not* really create another collection. Instead the `reversed` method creates a *view* upon the original collection that presents its elements in a reversed encounter order.

```java
String[] myArray = { "alpha" , "beta" , "gamma" };
SequencedCollection < String > strings = List.of( myArray );

System.out.println( "strings.toString() = " + strings );
System.out.println( "strings.reversed().toString() = " + strings.reversed().toString() );
```

When run:

```
strings.toString() = [alpha, beta, gamma]
strings.reversed().toString() = [gamma, beta, alpha]
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
    // inizliase the array 
        int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
    // we start from reservse so we write like this 
        for(int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
```

In the following code, we start the value of the array from (length - 1) to 0
line in the code i start from 4 to 0 when we run the loop as in the 4 index we
have 5 value so 5 will print after printing the value of i will be minus so it will be 3 now and it array 3 index we have 4 value of an array and it goes the same as i value becomes 0 then loop we terminate.